# changing text in an MXD textbox with items from a list in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, text

I am trying to create a text label for a series of maps over time. I have a text box with the element name "DateBox" in my mxd. As a filler, it says "Week # here". I want to it say "Week XX", where XX refers to the week number. I am using arcgis 10.3.

I have tried:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env 
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\GIS_User\Output"
map_mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\GIS_User\Output\timelapse.mxd")

for XX in range(1,121): 
    for TextElement in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(map_mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if TextElementName == "DateBox":
            TextElement.text = 'Week ' + str(XX)
        print TextElement.text
```

The arcpy window in ArcMap prints the text and shows that it successfully loops from Week 1 to Week 120. However, this change is not reflected in the textbox of the map document. The textbox itself still holds my original filler text "Week # here" and shows no changes when I run this code.

Comment: remember to use `map_mxd.save()` to save your MXD after the script is run.  Or use `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` to run it on the currently open MXD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the "CURRENT" map I think what you may be missing is:

```
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

at the end of each iteration.

Comment: `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` worked to refresh the view, but did not produce any changes in the displayed text. I am trying to incorporate either `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")` or `map_mxd.save()` into the loop. The first runs but produces no changes, while the second gives me this error:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 850, in save
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.save(*gp_fixargs((), True)))
IOError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.  Check to make sure you have write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your document.`

Comment: @MonMo That sounds like a new question because it would seem to be using a different code snippet to the one presented in this question.  Consequently, I think you should research/ask it separately.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I think it has something to do with transferring the mxd file to a new computer a while back, but you're right, it is a separate topic.

Comment: Turns out, `map_mxd.save()` was not needed. The text on the display was not changing, but checking a jpg export of the map showed that `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` worked and the text had the appropriate week numbers when the jpg files were viewed separately.